# regex match '<'

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need use javascript regex to match '<' as an operator, not html markup.

Here is sample data:

```
length(9)>8 [12]>[11] <span class="css">99</span>
```

Here is [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lK6vF3/1)

Comment: sorry, it is a typo. it should be '>'.

Comment: here is the updated [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lK6vF3/2)

Comment: Can you provide more background on your problem?  At first glance, I might opt for parsing the XML structure into a tree, and then using a very simple regex (maybe) to identify the `>` and `<` operators.

Comment: I am working on a complicated parser for user input. I need a regex to match > or < as an operator. At first, I want to use negative lookahead, but javascript does not support it. please focus on creating a almighty regex. that is all I need.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with algebra, you might be able to use something like `/.{3}>.{3}/gi` to give you the 3 symbols either side of the operator/tag.  Then match for `[a-zA-Z]` - if you get a match, it will be a tag.  If it consists only of space, parentheses, digits, etc, it will be an operator.  Hardly ideal, but depending on your data structure, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead on an extended string to exclude strings with a letter in any one of the 3 positions before the `>`, then extract the operators from those strings (once you've got rid of the strings that don't match):

```js
var str = 'length(9)>8 [12]>[11] <span class="css">99</span> "123">"122"';
var operators = str.match(/(?:(?![a-z]).){3}>/g);
console.log(operators);  //returns ["(9)>", "12]>", "23">"]
for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
  console.log(operators[i].match(/>/g));
  // returns  [">"][">"][">"]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I use this regex: /\s>\s/g just for a temporary solution.